# Large file upload with Angular/Core 2.2

Tags: angular, .net-core

I'm trying to upload files from Angular 8 to .net Core 2.2 controller and keep getting errors when trying to upload anything over 28mb but only when deployed to Azure.  Locally, I have no issues and can upload up to 100mb.  I don't see any errors being logged on the server.  The console shows me a CORS error and "Unknown Error".

I've followed the sample given here:  https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/2.x/SampleApp for setting up my .net core 2.2 controller to upload a file over 28mb.

Here is my angular service :

```
     const url = `${this.publicApiBaseUrl}client/${clientId}/account/${accountId}/case/${caseId}/attachment`;
        fileData.append('data', JSON.stringify({'questionId': questionId, 'caseId': caseId}));
        return this.httpClient.post(url, fileData, {
            headers: this.appService.getUploadHttpHeaders(),
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events'
        }).pipe(map((resData) => {
          const res: any = resData;
          if (res) {
              return res;
          }
      }),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        this.appService.showResponseErrorMsg(error.message);
        return observableThrowError(error);
      }));
```

Any suggestions for what else I can try?

Comment: `The console shows me a CORS error and "Unknown Error"` - What is the CORS error?  Also, if it uploads 28mb fine but nothing more, then it may be due to something timing out in the HTTP request, if there's a reverse proxy or load balancer for request timeouts, and the 28mb just correlates to your connection speed.

Comment: The cors error is "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-domain.com/v1/client/eae69d02-3b32-4a7b-b18d-0a137efb9306/account/9c0b2e0b-9012-4a2b-a932-08d7b61bff61/case/c5621f86-3f6b-4076-7c9d-08d7ba1bb912/attachment' from origin 'https://my-domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

The 28mb is a limit of .net core file uploads but should be able to override it with

[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]
[RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]

Comment: I'm not sure how the CORS and 28mb issue are related (surely if CORS is failing, you wouldn't be able to upload anything, regardless of size).  But, for the 28mb issue, my thinking is that it may be closing the connection after 60 seconds, or some time interval.  Can you validate that this isn't the case?

Comment: It's throwing the error on a 38mb file after 19 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what it could be, good luck!

Comment: The console log for failures isn't always as helpful as it should be. For example, if a request errors out and the response doesn't include the CORS headers, you'll get the "blocked by CORS policy" log entry with no good information. I'd recommend trying again, but looking at the information returned in the Network window instead of the console log.